# Why is data validation only checking the first entry?

Tags: c++

The following code should check all the entries if founds "badIndex" which is a non integer number, it must print it and also if it founds correct input which is for sure only digits entry, it should print all the digits.

**EX bad input:** 123Y123 here Y is a bad input and it should print it along "badIndex".

**EX good input:** 123123 is agood input and it should print it along "goodIndex".

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isThisHuman(const string& userInput)
{
   int badIndex;
   int goodIndex;
   for (int userInputCounter = 0; userInputCounter < userInput.length(); userInputCounter ++)
   {
      if(!(userInput [userInputCounter] >=48 && userInput [userInputCounter] <=57))
         {
            badIndex = userInputCounter;
            cout << "The value Entered: [" << userInput[badIndex] << "] is not a number. \n" << '\n';
            return false;
         }else
            goodIndex = userInputCounter;
            cout << "The value you have entered: [" << userInput[goodIndex] << "] is a number. Success congratulations you are not a bot" << '\n';
            return true;
   }
}
void botVerification();

int main()
{
   botVerification();
   return 0;
}
void botVerification()
{
   string botInput;
   bool isHuman;
   do
   {
      cout << "Enter the number to identify that you are not a bot: ";
      cin >> botInput;
      isHuman = isThisHuman (botInput);
      if(isHuman)
      {
         cout << "Success \n" << '\n';
      }else cout << "Not Success" << '\n';
   }while (!(isHuman));
}
```

Comment: Because `return` statement is executed in both branch at the first iteration.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes it fixed the issue and created another issue, first printing the bad input as bad input and then  checking all the input again and printing all the input as a valid input. I think it can be fixed with including limits ?

Comment: I recommend that you learn about [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). And please try to avoid the use of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: Also please make sure that your [mcve] replicates the problem you ask about *only*. If there are other problems then those tend to draw attention away from the problem you ask about. And unless you're asking about build errors, make sure the code *builds*.

Comment: Lastly, please learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through the code statement by statement to see what really happens. If you did that, you should find out the problem much faster than it took to write this question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes the code I write is building successfully.

Comment: Ah yes, it builds. I misread it because the indentation is off so I didn't realize that you're missing a `{}` pair.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Where I have missed it Please point it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224167/discussion-between-indiana-jones-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: In the `else` branch. The code doesn't match the indentation you have. Only the assignment is in the `else`, the rest are outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it:

First, count the characters that are digit with `std::isdigit`, if it's not a digit, then print it.

And if the count is equals to the length of the input, print the input is good and return true, else return false:

```cpp
bool isThisHuman(const std::string& userInput)
{
    // Check the numbers of digits is equals to the length of the input:
    if(std::count_if(userInput.begin(), userInput.end(),
        [](unsigned char c)
        {
            // If it is not a digit, print the character:
            if(!std::isdigit(c))
            {
                std::cout << "[" << c << "] is not a number!\n";
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }) == userInput.length())
    {
        // If the numbers of digit is equals to the length of the input, print the number and return true:
        std::cout << "[" << userInput << "] is a number!";
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Here I used `<algorithm>` for `std::count_if` and `<cctype>` for `std::isdigit`.

Without them, you could also do:

```cpp
bool isThisHuman2(const std::string& userInput)
{
    int goodCount = 0;
    for(unsigned char c : userInput)
    {
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            ++goodCount;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "[" << c << "] is not a number!\n";
        }
    }
    if(goodCount == userInput.size())
    {
        std::cout << "[" << userInput << "] is a number!";
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ 0 is always false and you can also use it by checking the bool as well at the same time when checking the **userInput.length()** and also you don't need **goodIndex** if the userInput is valid you just need to print it back as it is with the same name.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    bool isThisHuman(const string& userInput)
    {
       int badIndex;
       //int goodIndex;
       for (int userInputCounter = 0; userInputCounter < userInput.length() && isThisHuman; userInputCounter ++)
       {
          if(!(userInput [userInputCounter] >=48 && userInput [userInputCounter] <=57))
             {
                badIndex = userInputCounter;
                cout << "The value Entered: [" << userInput[badIndex] << "] is not a number. \n" << '\n';
                return false;
             }else if (!(userInput [userInputCounter] <=48 && userInput [userInputCounter] >=57))
                {
                //goodIndex = userInputCounter;
                cout << "The value you have entered: [" << userInput << "] contains numbers. Success congratulations you are not a bot" << '\n';
                return true;
                }
       }
    }
    void botVerification();
    int main()
    {
       botVerification();
       return 0;
    }
    void botVerification()
    {
       string botInput;
       bool isHuman;
       do
       {
          cout << "Enter the number to identify that you are not a bot: ";
          cin >> botInput;
          isHuman = isThisHuman (botInput);
          if(isHuman)
          {
             cout << "Success \n" << '\n';
          }else cout << "Not Success" << '\n';
       }while (!(isHuman));
    }
```

Comment: still printing the valid input along with bad input, and yes I really don't need to declare goodIndex.